# how to rewrite jQuery ToggleClass and if/else code into vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small jQuery code for handling some toggle class and HTML5 local-storage and I would like to convert it into a modern vanilla JS code.
I have to say I have no clue where to start.

Can someone by any chance show me the correct approach for a modern JS code for this?  I would really appreciate it.

example demo:
http://jsbin.com/wimojapowo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```js
$('#container').toggleClass(localStorage.toggled);

$('.bar-toggle').on('click', function() {
  //localstorage values are always strings (no booleans)  
  if (localStorage.toggled != "with_toggle") {
    $('#container').toggleClass("with_toggle", true);
    localStorage.toggled = "with_toggle";
  } else {
    $('#container').toggleClass("with_toggle", false);
    localStorage.toggled = "";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly note that your jQuery example is more complicated than it needs to be. You can just do this:

```
$('.bar-toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('#container').toggleClass("with_toggle", localStorage.toggled != "with_toggle");
  localStorage.toggled = localStorage.toggled == "with_toggle" ? '' : 'with_toggle';
});
```

To convert this to plain JS you can use the `classList.toggle()` method:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.bar-toggle').forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle("with_toggle", localStorage.toggled != "with_toggle");
    localStorage.toggled = localStorage.toggled == "with_toggle" ? '' : 'with_toggle';
  });
})
```

More info on `classList` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)